# Login with CakePHP and jQuery Mobile

Tags: ajax, cakephp, jquery-mobile, authentication

I'm building a mobile application with CakePHP 2.3 and jQuery Mobile.

I'm having a tough time making the login work. 
I send out links that contain surveys, and if the user is not logged in on their mobile browser, it first makes them sign in.

The problem is that the first time, it just refreshes to a blank page. If you close the page and reopen the link, it works, but that sucks. I'd like it to just redirect correctly.

Here's the view for login:

```
<div class="users form">
    <?= $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
    <fieldset>
    <?
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?
    $options = array(
        'label' => 'Login',
        'rel' => 'external',
        'data-ajax' => false
    );
    ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end($options); ?>
</div>
```

As you can see, I tried `rel=external` and `data-ajax=false`.

Putting the login on the same page somehow might solve the issue, but that seems like it defeats the purpose of using CakePHP in the first place.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not going to create an AJAX form in Cake.

You have to disable the default action of the form, and then submit the data via Javascript. You can use the built in JsHelper in Cake to do this.

To disable auto submitting of the form you need to pass this to the `create` method.

> Form->create('User',array('default'=>false)); ?>

You can then use the `serializeForm` method of the JsHelper.

```
<?php
$data = $this->Js->get('#UserForm')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
$this->Js->get('#UserForm')->event(
      'submit',
      $this->Js->request(
        array('action' => 'save'),
        array(
                'update' => '#UserForm',
                'data' => $data,
                'async' => true,    
                'dataExpression'=>true,
                'method' => 'POST'
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

Note: The above requires that you place the output from JsHelper in the proper location of your layout.

You can now render the form like this.

```
<div class="users form">
    <?= $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
    <?= $this->Form->create('User',array('default'=>false)); ?>
    <fieldset>
    <?
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?
    $options = array(
        'label' => 'Login',
    );
    ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end($options); ?>
</div>
```

This off the top of my head. So it's not test.

Comment: awesome! this worked, thank you so much! I knew there had to be something built-in for this.

Comment: now, how would I do this for logout, which is just a hyperlink?

Comment: If the user interface changes when logged out, then just `$this->redirect(..)` in the logout action somewhere like the home page. Otherwise you can just do a silent AJAX call.

Comment: The auth component has it defined as the login page. I tried implementing the silent AJAX call, but it didn't change anything. Should I do something like preventing default on clicking the logout link button? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not using the Auth from Cake, but you want to call `$this->Auth->logout()` from your controller's logout action. This might classify as a new question.

Comment: hmmmm, that is what I'm using. If I can't find a solution soon I'll make sure to put up a new question.